# Let $X$ be a compact metrizable space. Let $H(X)$ be the set of homeomorphisms of $X$. Then $H(X)$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set in $C(X, X)$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

**The Statement**: Let $X$ be a compact metrizable space. Let $H(X)$ be the set of homeomorphisms of $X$. Then $H(X)$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set in $C(X, X)$, the space of all continuous functions from $X$ to $X$ with the topology induced by the uniform/sup metric. Here $G_{\delta}$ is a set of the form $\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\cap}U_n$, where $U_n$ are open.

**Source**: *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Alexander S. Kechris.

**My Attempt**: It suffices to show that $H(X)$ is closed in $C(X, X)$, i.e., $H_c(X):=C(X, X)-H(X)$ is open. To that end, let $f\in H_c(X)$ be arbitrary. Then either $f$ is not bijective or $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Case I: $f$ is not bijective. Then $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x\neq y$. **Screeching halt**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting. I've been able to handle all cases except the following one: "if $f\in C(X,X)$ is surjective but not injective, then show that there is a neighbourhood of $f$ in $C(X,X)$ disjoint from $H(X)$".

Comment: I don't think $H(X)$ is closed in $C(X,X)$. Consider $X=[0,1]$ and let $f_n:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be defined through $f_n(0)=0$, $f_n(1)=1$ and $f_n(1/2)=1/(n+1)$. Extend this piecewise linearly to whole $X$. Then each $f_n$ is a homeomorphism, but the limit is constant $0$ over $[0,1/2]$, while it is continuous. Thus $H(X)$ is not closed.

Comment: @freakish I appreciate the example but how exactly does $f_n\to 0$ over $[0, 1/2]$ show that $H([0, 1])$ is not closed?

Comment: @DickGrayson Because a constant function over $[0,1/2]$ cannot be a homeomorphism. And so you have a sequence of homeomorphisms converging to a non-homeomorphism (but still continuous function).

Comment: @freakish Not quite. You have only shown that $(f_n|_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]})$ converges to $0$ on $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$, but $(f_n)$ itself may not converge on $[0, 1]$ at all. In fact, even if it does converge, it won't converge to $0$ since $f_n(1)=1\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ so $d(f_n, 0)\geq1\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @freakish On a second thought, no sequence of homeomorphisms on $[0, 1]$ will ever converge to a constant: homeomorphisms are bijective, thus each $f_n$ must attain both $0$ and $1$. So if $(f_n)$ converges to a constant, that constant must be both $0$ and $1$, which is impossible.

Comment: @DickGrayson look at my construction again. The sequence converges to constant zero at $[0,1/2]$ while at $[1/2,1]$ to straight line from $0$ to $1$. It is a piecewise linear function that is continuous but not a homeomorphism. It will be easier to see if you draw my sequence. Each $f_n$ is composed of two straight lines, and so is the limit. I designed this carefuly so it works correctly.

Comment: @freakish I see-I misunderstood your $(f_n)$ from the start. That indeed works!

Comment: @DickGrayson where exactly is this claim (i.e. $H(X)$ is $G_\delta$) in the book? Maybe there's some hint for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146737/discussion-between-dick-grayson-and-freakish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all $H(X)$ is not necessarily closed in $C(X,X)$. A concrete example is $X=[0,1]$ and then you define $f_n:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ via

$$f_n(0)=0$$
$$f_n(1)=1$$
$$f_n(1/2)=1/n$$

and extend this piecewise linearly to whole $[0,1]$. So each $f_n$ is glueing of two straight lines.

Then each $f_n$ is a homeomorphism but the limit is constant zero at $[0,1/2]$, while a straight line from $0$ to $1$ at $[1/2,1]$.

And thus we have a sequenece of homeomorphisms convergent to a continuous non-homeomorphism.

Btw, it is not hard to see that $H([0,1])$ is also not open, by slightly modifying a homeomorphism $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ inside small enough ball in $[0,1]$.

---

But indeed, the $H(X)$ is $G_\delta$ in $C(X,X)$. And the hint for that can be found in the book itself. Given $d_u$ to be the uniform/sup metric the book says:

> A compatible complete metric is $\rho(f,g)=d_u(f,g)+d_u(f^{-1},g^{-1})$

This probably needs verification. But if it is the case, then $H(X)$ is a completely metrizable subspace of $C(X,X)$. And that is equivalent to the fact that $H(X)$ is $G_\delta$, assuming you already know that $C(X,X)$ itself is complete (which is true at least for compact $X$).